# i have function to update but its take too long time execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

hy, i have a function to update data table in my postgresql but to execution the function is take too long time. however, when I run it as a regular update statement query it doesn't take any long time.

my function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."f_ranking"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$BEGIN
    
UPDATE t_personal_stat
set "RANKG" = rr.rk
FROM
    (
SELECT
rank() over (order by PS."PONTOT" DESC, P."NAM" ASC ) as rk,
PS."USCD",PS."LEVL",PS."PONTOT"
FROM
t_personal_stat PS JOIN t_personal P ON P."USCD"=PS."USCD"
)rr
WHERE
t_personal_stat."USCD"=rr."USCD";

    RETURN NEW;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

I hope to reduce the execution time to be faster

Answer (score 2):

Set in `postgresql.conf`:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'auto_explain'
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1s  # or whatever else you want
auto_explain.log_analyze = on
auto_explain.log_buffers = on
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on
```

Then restart PostgreSQL. That will write the execution plan of all long running statements to the log, so that you can analyze the problem.

**Warning:** `auto_explain.log_analyze = on` causes a notable performance impact.